# Elasticsearch Aggregation sorting

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation

My Elasticsearch mapping is

```
{
  "mappings" : {
     "loc" : {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "properties" : {
            "geoip" : {
                "properties" : {
                "location" : { "type": "geo_point"}
                }
            },
        "lon" : { "type" : "double" },
        "lat" : { "type" : "double" },
        "altitude" : { "type" : "double" },
        "id" : { "type" : "long" },
        "date" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "epoch_millis" },
        "ip" : { "type" : "string" },
        "port" : { "type" : "string" }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to sort by time.
So i made query.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "0.2km",
                    "geoip.location" : {
                        "lat" : 36.773353,
                        "lon" : 126.933847
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size" : 0,
    "sort" : { "date" : { "order" : "desc" } },
    "aggs" : {
        "ids" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "id"
            },
        "aggs" : {
            "dedup_docs" : {
                "top_hits" : {"size" : 1}
            }
        }
    }
   }
}
```

I want to return the latest time by grouping the results of applying the gps filter by id and sorting in chronological order.

However, the date value of the result is an unordered result.
I do not know how to modify the query.

Comment: Where you need to sort? In query part(hits) or in aggregation part?

Comment: aggregation part!!